# GitHub Actions: how to build a pull request as if it were merged?

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

I'm very excited about GitHub Actions.

I use Travis-CI and AppVeyor now, which have "PR" (pull request) builds that build the code as if the pull request were merged.

I would like to use GitHub Actions for continuous integration, but it seems GitHub Actions only supports building pushed commits, not the result of the merge. How do I achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/15#issuecomment-524093065 and https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/15#issuecomment-524107344, if you set your workflow to trigger on the `pull_request` event rather than the `push` event, the `GITHUB_SHA` will be the merge commit, so the `checkout` action will check out the result of the merge, which you can then build and run unit tests on.

It's also officially documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request):

> `GITHUB_SHA` = Last merge commit on the `GITHUB_REF` branch
> `GITHUB_REF` = PR merge branch `refs/pull/:prNumber/merge`

<del>Disclaimer: I haven't gotten into the beta yet, so I can't verify this information for myself; I can just pass on what others have said worked for them.</del>

I've gotten into the beta now, so I can confirm that this works. I ran a build of the following workflow in [my test repo](https://github.com/rmunn/Testing):

```
name: Build PR

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  build:

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macOS-latest]
        dotnet: [2.2.402, 3.0.100-rc1-014190]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    
    steps:
    # ... trimmed ...
    - name: Dump GitHub context
      env:
        GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
      run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
      if: runner.os != 'Windows'
    # ... trimmed ...
```

[Here's a build log of that workflow running](https://github.com/rmunn/Testing/runs/227805618). The PR is [here](https://github.com/rmunn/Testing/pulls); the first commit on that PR is commit ID `ec81c6f`:

[image: Picture evidence of commit ID]

When I ran `git fetch origin pull/10/merge:merge-pr-10` to fetch the merge commit, the commit I got was `f1ea865`, a merge of `ec81c6f` onto `44a09bc` (which was the latest commit on my `master` branch at the time that PR was created). And notice the SHA that was actually built:

[image: Picture evidence of build SHA]

So just by using `on: [pull_request]` as the triggering event of my workflow, it did what I wanted. If you look at [the PR's history](https://github.com/rmunn/Testing/pull/10), you'll see that I tried several things to see what triggered a new build: adding a comment, closing the repo, opening the repo... Here's what I found.

- Adding a comment did **NOT** trigger a new workflow run
- Pushing a new commit **DID** trigger a new workflow run
- Closing the PR did **NOT** trigger a new workflow run
- Reopening the PR **DID** trigger a new workflow run
- Adding a label to the PR did **NOT** trigger a new workflow run
- Removing a label from the PR did **NOT** trigger a new workflow run

Which is all as I would have expected.

Comment: Did pushing new commit to master trigger the pipeline? It should as the merge result would be different

Comment: Does the pipeline run again every time the target branch has a new commit until the PR is merged?