# During a PR action on GitHub, what version of the code is actually run?

Tags: github, github-actions

I've tried to read the GitHub documentation on this and tried to google some information about it, but either the information is missing or I'm just unable to understand it :)

Either way, I'll use an example (python) to illustrate the problem:

`foo.py` on `master`:

```
my_list = [
    1,
    2,
]
assert len(my_list) == 2
```

So far, so good.

Create new branch:

`foo.py` on branch `feat_a`

```
my_list = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
]
assert len(my_list) == 3
```

And a separate feature branch:

`foo.py` on branch `feat_b`

```
my_list = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
]
assert len(my_list) == 3
```

I then merge `feat_a` into `master`. The problem now is that my PR for `feat_b` is perfectly mergeable which will create the list with 4 items from 0 to 3. But the assert statement will fail after the merge commit takes place. In other words, I have two branches that runs perfectly fine on their own and are mergeable, but are in a bad state AFTER the merge commit.

So my question is this:
When I run a GitHub action, how can I make sure that the action runs the merged code? Is this the default behavior or not?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683943/github-actions-how-to-build-a-pull-request-as-if-it-were-merged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run on the merged code if you, f.e., use the [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action with default values.

If you look at the [event data](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) of a pull request you get something like the following (shortened)

```
{
  "ref": "refs/pull/1/merge",
  "sha": "<sha-1>",
  "event": {
    "number": 1,
    "pull_request": {
      "head": {
        "ref": "<base-branch>",
        "sha": "<sha-2>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the hash the workflow is running on is different to the hash of the commit on the base branch of your pull request.