# Github Actions which branch used on PR

Tags: github, github-actions

I am just getting started with Github actions. In my test workflow I am firing the workflow on PRs to the develop branch.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - develop
```

This works fine, but my question is what branch is being built when this runs. Because this action runs before the merge is actually complete (on PR creation) is it just building the source branch? If so, how is that helpful since it isn't taking the changes the PRs code will make to the target branch.

If it is building the target branch it doesnt make sense because the code isn't actually merged yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Actions: how to build a pull request as if it were merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683943/github-actions-how-to-build-a-pull-request-as-if-it-were-merged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the documentation for the `pull_request` event it tells you what the environment variables `GITHUB_SHA` and `GITHUB_REF` will be for this event.

> **GITHUB_SHA**: Last merge commit on the **GITHUB_REF** branch
>
> **GITHUB_REF**: PR merge branch refs/pull/:prNumber/merge

ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request

When you use the official `actions/checkout` action, these are the settings it uses by default if you don't supply any inputs.

What that means is that by default, `pull_request` events will checkout a merge commit from the pull request head to the base. This allows you to test against what the source would look like if it was already merged.